# Calculating bearing in with geodesic coordinates

Tags: mapping, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geodesic-sphere

I am attempting to calculate the bearing from an object with geodesic coords given by latitude/longitude and a heading to another object at different latitude/longitude coordinates.

A rough sketch of the problem is

[image]

where the triangle represents object one, the arrow represents object one's heading, and the square represents object two.

I am aware this can be done using the haversine formula, as in , but how would one do this while  simultaneously taking spheroid earth into consideration.

Comment: For complex problems, I recommend to use tested libraries, e.g. https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/ . Or at minimum I would read their code, to see how they solved it, and all problems about numeric approximations and special cases.

Comment: I browsed through their functions but I don't believe there is one that solves this problem?

Comment: It is in the example: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/C/: you give lat/long of two points and you get distances and the two azimuth (at point 1 and at point 2).  Check also https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/C/geodesic_8h.html#a622f12217dff0370db4f96e80a71f605

Comment: This doesn't take the heading of object 1 into consideration though? Maybe I am misunderstanding the meaning of the azimuth

Comment: The absolute bearing is the same as azimuth (0 degree is "to north"). You are looking (as I understand) the relative bearing, so just the difference between your actual heading and the expected bearing. Navigation terminology is different to geodetics terminology, so you should try with few examples, to see if you interpreted correctly (but with geodetics, this is an important step: too many different conventions and hidden assumptions). In any case, I think it is good to use good geodetics libraries (if you want good precision, and if you want a spheroid, you are asking precision)

Comment: But in this case it doesn't necessarily play well right? Because object 1 wont' necessarily be point towards object 2. But yeah I am definitely more used to navigation terminology, the geodetics terminology is slightly confusing.